# Tighest Gap $\|x\|_1/\|x\|_2$ between $\ell^1$ and $\ell^2$ norms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, convex-optimization, norms

I'm looking specifically at the optimization problem
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{maximize: }& n - \frac{\|\lambda\|_1^2}{\|\lambda\|_2^2}\\
\text{subj. to: }& \lambda \succeq \epsilon\mathbf{1}
\end{align*}
$$
over $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $\epsilon\geq 0$ is some constant. This is equivalent to the problem
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize: }& \frac{\|\lambda\|_1}{\|\lambda\|_2}\\
\text{subj. to: }& \lambda \succeq \epsilon\mathbf{1}
\end{align*}
$$
which at least looks cleaner, and is in fact a [concave fractional program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_programming#Concave_fractional_programs) (at least if $\epsilon$ is positive).

**Question:** Is there a way to bound the optimal value of the original objective function? Preferably can we show that for some small (in $n$) $\epsilon$ that the optimal $n - \frac{\|\lambda\|_1^2}{\|\lambda\|_2^2} < 1$?

**When $\epsilon=0$:** In this case we can rely on the tight bound $\|x\|_2 \leq \|x\|_1$ to have an optimal value of $n - \frac{\|\lambda^\star\|_1^2}{\|\lambda^\star\|_2^2} = n-1$.

Comment: The constraint that $\lambda_j\ge\epsilon$ (if I understand your notation correctly) doesn't do anything, of course you can still get arbitrarily close to the optimal value $1$ with vectors such as $\lambda=(N,\epsilon,\ldots, \epsilon)$, $N\gg 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(EDIT: changing this to at least solve the stated problem...)

We first look for the optimal vector for fixed $\|\lambda\|_1=M$. Hence the problem is: maximize $\|\lambda\|_2^2$ s.t. $\|\lambda\|_1=M$, $\lambda\geq \varepsilon\mathbf{1}$.

The standard trick to solve this kind of inequalities is called *unsmoothing*, and goes as follows. Start from any feasible point, and assume without loss of generality that $\lambda_1\geq \lambda_j$ for each $j$.

Now, a simple computation shows that replacing $\lambda_1,\lambda_j$ with $\lambda_1+\delta,\lambda_j-\delta$ increases the objective function. (Remark: this is essentially equivalent to noticing that $t^2 + (\lambda_1+\lambda_j-t)^2$ is convex in $t$, so its maximum must be at one end of the domain).

Hence, with $n-1$ of these replacement steps, you arrive to $(M-(n-1)\varepsilon,\varepsilon,\varepsilon,\dots,\varepsilon)$, and your objective function has increased at each step. This proves that the maxima are $(M-(n-1)\varepsilon,\varepsilon,\varepsilon,\dots,\varepsilon)$ and its cyclic permutations.

Now we get 
$$
\frac{\|\lambda\|_1}{\|\lambda\|_2} \leq \frac{M}{\sqrt{(M-(n-1)\varepsilon)^2+(n-1)\varepsilon^2}}
$$
which is now a univariate problem.

Comment: I think, we can not assume $\|x\|_1=1$. If we fix $\|x\|_1$, the minimum is indeed obtained when all but one coordinates are equal to $\varepsilon$ and the rest is some $t \varepsilon$, $t\geqslant 1$. We have to minimize $(t+(n-1))/\sqrt{t^2+(n-1)}$.

Comment: Minimum is not attained, infimum is for $t=\infty$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov You are correct, my mistake -- I solved a slightly different problem.

Comment: (Nevertheless, these computations can be used to show that the optimum is $(M-(n-1)\varepsilon,\varepsilon,\varepsilon,\dots,\varepsilon)$ for fixed $\|x\|_1=M$, and then the rest of the problem is simple. --- There are probably simpler solutions, but at least this gives one.)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni thanks for the insight on this. Do you have a reference to a text/paper discussing 'unsmoothing' in more detail? (out of curiosity more than anything)

Comment: @ConnerDiPaolo There is something on www.math.cmu.edu/~ploh/docs/math/mop2008/convexity-soln.pdf. It's ultimately just a convexity idea.

Comment: Awesome thank you (both) for the insight!